# What's the difference between these approaches for scheduling tasks on Kubernetes?

Tags: airflow

I've run into a few disparate approaches for scheduling an airflow task on a Kubernetes pod and I haven't been able to figure out what the differences are, and when I should prefer one style over another.

For context, my local airflow test instance is configured to use the `KubernetesExecutor` and I'm scheduling these tasks on a local Kubernetes cluster.

1. First style (frankly, I didn't expect this to work - what is it
   using as a base image?)

```
dag = DAG('ex1', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)

# Single Operator DAG
BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)
```

2. Second style.  I encountered this [here](https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-kubernetes-executor/)

```
dag = DAG('ex2', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)

# Why do you need to specify the executor when the executor is already configured via airflow.cfg?
BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag,
    executor_config={"KubernetesExecutor": {"image": "ubuntu:1604"}})
```

3. Third style via `KubernetesPodOperator` This seems like the most flexible (you can specify ANY container, with ANY arguments), so perhaps that's the only advantage?  However, given a scenario where I was simply calling a bash script or a python script, is there any difference between this and approach 1 or 2 (either with BashOperator or PythonOperator)?

```
dag = DAG('ex3', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)

KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='default',
                          image="ubuntu:1604",
                          cmds=["/bin/bash","-c"],
                          arguments=["echo hello world"],
                          labels={"foo": "bar"},
                          name="EchoInAUbuntuContainer",
                          task_id="testUbuntuEcho",
                          get_logs=True,
                          dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `KubernetesPodOperator` is meant for the cases where you're using a non-kubernetes executor, and you want to run an image on Kubernetes.
2. If you opt to use the `KubernetesExecutor`, then operators like `BashOperator` and `PythonOperator` will be scheduled on Kubernetes (though it's unclear what image they use if you don't specify one).